# Are python project dependencies are still required to be installed after compilation with PyInstaller?

Tags: python, python-3.x, pyinstaller

I just started learning Python and I built a simple windows file search application with Python 3. Now I want to compile and convert it to .exe using PyInstaller. Do still all dependencies like imported OS and other built-in Python libraries are required to be installed by .exe version users?

Sorry if I'm not clear enough.
Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

No, you don't need the original libraries to run the `.exe` file created with the installer. if you use `pyinstaller` with `–onefile –windowed` flags, it will package all of the libraries that are necessary to run your program with that file.

The resulting package will not require any external dependencies to run.

An in-depth explanation can be [found here](https://pyinstaller.readthedocs.io/en/stable/operating-mode.html).

Comment: Thanks Simas, your answer and the link you provided answered everything I needed to know.